# how to overload << operator of class template with non-type parameter?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload `operator<<` of a class template , like this:

```
template<int V1,int V2>
class Screen
{
    template<int T1,int T2> friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &,Screen<T1,T2>&);  
    private:
        int width;  
        int length;
    public:
        Screen():width(V1),length(V2){}
};
template<int T1,int T2>
ostream& operator<< (ostream &os,Screen<T1,T2> &screen)
{
    os << screen.width << ' ' << screen.length;
    return os;
}
```

the code above is running corrent!but i want to know if there is any way to overload `operator<<` in a way by not setting it as a function template:

`friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &,Screen<T1,T2>&);`
?

Comment: `friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &,Screen<V1,V2>&);` doesn't work?

Comment: implement the function at the friend declaration point

Comment: @Henry: it does not work? what you you mean then by "is running corrent"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but you have to predeclare the template and use `<>` syntax:

```
template<int V1, int V2> class Screen;
template<int T1, int T2> ostream &operator<< (ostream &,Screen<T1,T2> &);
template<int V1, int V2>
class Screen
{
    friend ostream& operator<< <>(ostream &, Screen&);
    ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Good practice is to have some public function `printContent` like this -

```
void Screen::printContent(ostream &os)
{
    os << width << ' ' << length;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream &os,Screen<T1,T2> &screen)
{
    screen.printContent(os);
    return os;
}
```

thus you don't need any `friend`s